# Only edit the value in an MVC edit template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a settings class that is no more than `ID`, `Name`, `Value`.

I've done a basic controller scaffolding template and it works well.

the default code is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Value")] ConfigOption config)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(config).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(config);
}
```

I want the user to be able to change the setting values, but, not the name after clicking edit, so, I deleted the edit box from the page - however, this now causes the name to become blank upon saving.

I know I can do what I want by editing the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` part, manually finding the id and then performing my own mapping and saving, but, I haven't touched MVC since version 3 and I could swear it was easier/the edit template was neater back then.

...Is there a simpler way of just modifying one field? - I've even tried taking `Name` off the bind section, but, I can't say I fully understand that... I need to catch up on the new features.

Comment: You can always include a hidden input for the `Name` property, however the correct approach is to use a view model containing only the properties you want to edit and post back the view model. Then get the data model from the repository, update its properties based on the view model, then save the data model (no `[Bind]` attribute required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I did edit to use a view model, but, it kept wiping the name still. The answer below helped me. I was being silly/didn't understand how EF knew the view model was from the DB just by calling modified... but, read up a lot of documentation and it made sense.

Comment: The accepted answer is posting back a data model. You really should be using a view model (it would contain only one property (`Value`). You then get the data model and map the view model `Value` to the data model `Value` as per the accepted answer. And the use of your `[Bind]` attribute is pointless - there is no point specifying that all properties of your model be bound when, by default, they already are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTTP is stateless, you need to provide the name value also to the Edit method.
Just think it through, how can EF decide from an empty name value (what you have here right now) if it represent that you want the property unchanged or you want it to be set to empty.

You either place back the name field to the view as hidden, but you still should worry about that the user can change the value of the hidden field, or you should do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Value")]     ConfigOption model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var config=db.Configs.Find(model.ID);
     config.Value=model.Value;
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(config);
}
```

The Bind attribute next to the action's parameter is supposed to prevent the attack called mass assignment/overposting. Find out more here: http://ironshay.com/post/Mass-Assignment-Vulnerability-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx